# A proof of Hadamard three spheres using maximium principle.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I have this problem: Let $u:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\Delta u \geq 0$ in $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. If $r_{1},r_{2}$ are such that $B_{r_1}(0)\subset B_{r_2}(0) \subset \Omega$ and $M(r):=\max_{x\in\partial B_{r}(0)}u(x)$, prove that

$$M(r)\leq \dfrac{M(r_{1})(r^{2-n}-r_{2}^{2-n})+M(r_{2})(r_{1}^{2-n}-r^{2-n}))}{r_{1}^{2-n}-r_{2}^{2-n}} \hspace{10px} \forall r_1 < r < r_2 $$.

And it give us the next hint: define $\phi=a+\dfrac{b}{|x|^{n-2}}$, and $\phi(r_{1})=M(r_{1}),\phi(r_{2})=M(r_{2})$. Then compute a,b and use the maximum principle for $v=u-\phi$.

Well I find the $\phi(r)=\dfrac{M(r_{1})(r^{2-n}-r_{2}^{2-n})+M(r_{2})(r_{1}^{2-n}-r^{2-n}))}{r_{1}^{2-n}-r_{2}^{2-n}}$ , so its only see that $M(r)-\phi(r)\leq0$ , but i dont know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

$\phi$ should be a function of $x$ and not of $r$:
$$
\phi(x)=\frac{M(r_{1})(|x|^{2-n}-r_{2}^{2-n})+M(r_{2})(r_{1}^{2-n}-|x|^{2-n}))}{r_{1}^{2-n}-r_{2}^{2-n}}
$$

Assuming that $n \ge 3$, $\phi$ is *harmonic* in $\Bbb R^n \setminus \{ 0 \}$ (i.e. $\Delta \phi = 0$), so that $v = u - \phi$ is subharmonic in $A = \{ x \mid r_1 < | x | < r_2 \}$ (i.e. $\Delta v \ge 0$) and continuous on $\overline A$.

For $|x| = r \in \{ r_1, r_2 \} $ is
$$
 v(x) = u(x) - \phi(x) \le M(r) - \phi(x) = 0
$$
by construction, so that $v(x) \le 0$ on the boundary of $A$. The maximum principle then implies that $v(x) \le 0$ for all $x \in A$.

It follows that if $|x| = r$ with $r_1 < r < r_2$ then
$$
 u(x) \le \phi(x) = \frac{M(r_{1})(r^{2-n}-r_{2}^{2-n})+M(r_{2})(r_{1}^{2-n}-r^{2-n}))}{r_{1}^{2-n}-r_{2}^{2-n}}
$$
and that gives the desired inequality.

Comment: Why $u(x) - \phi(x) \leq M(r) - \phi(x) \leq 0$?

Comment: @JF2020: If $|x| = r$ then $u(x) \le M(r)$. And $M(r) = \phi(x)$ if $r$ is $r_1$ or $r_2$, that is how you construct the function $\phi$.

Comment: @JF2020: Please let me know if anything is still unclear.